# Gulp Livereload after ALL files have been compiled?

Tags: javascript, gulp, synchronous

I have a problem that I thought might be common to many people, but it seems I'm not right. So I hope someone can help, since I can't find the answer in the Gulp documents.

Right now my gulpfile.js has the following content:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
var jeet = require('jeet');
var nib = require('nib');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var sources = {
  jade: "jade/**/*.jade",
  partials: "partials/**/*.jade",
  stylus: "styl/**/*.styl",
  scripts: "js/**/*.js"
};

// Define destinations object

var destinations = {
  html: "dist/",
  css: "dist/css",
  js: "dist/js"
};

// Compile and copy Jade
gulp.task("jade", function(event) {
  return gulp.src(sources.jade)
  .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.html))
});

// Compile and copy Stylus
gulp.task("stylus", function(event) {
  return gulp.src(sources.stylus).pipe(stylus({
    use: [nib(), jeet()],
    import: [
      'nib',
      'jeet'
    ],
    style: "compressed"
  })).pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.css));
});

// Minify and copy all JavaScript
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src(sources.scripts)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.js));
});

// Server
gulp.task('server', function () {
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/dist/'));
  app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0');
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(sources.jade, ["jade"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.partials, ["jade"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.stylus, ["stylus"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.scripts, ["scripts"]);
});

// Define default task
gulp.task("default", ["jade", "stylus", "scripts", "server", "watch"], function(){
  gulp.watch([
    sources.jade,
    sources.partials,
    sources.stylus,
    sources.scripts,
  ]).on('change', function(event) {
    livereload.changed();
    console.log('File', event.path, 'was', event.type);
    console.log('LiveReload is triggered');
  });
});
```

What happens is that I have more than 1 jade file. When I am working on - say - the 10nth in alphabetical order, and I change it, I get the livereload executed right away. The problem is that it reloads the browser tab before all jade files finish compiling and being copied to the destination, therefore the file I am currently working on is not even compiled when the refresh happens. Is there a way I can chain the reloading after a task is completed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to notify livereload of changes.
In your tasks you have to add the livereload option in the end of the pipe.

For example in the *jade* task:

```
gulp.task("jade", function(event) {
  return gulp.src(sources.jade)
  .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.html))
  .pipe(livereload());
});
```

I do not try this code in your Gulpfile, but I think it works.

Regards.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still does not work very well. That's why I've put the livereload triggers in the default task, at the bottom - I have tried to make it fire at the very end. If I use the way you suggest, all that happens is that lovereload fires after the first of the jade files is compiled (I guess this task is executed for all jade files every time). This results in livereloading after the first of the jade files is compiled and not reloading after the last one is. If I am working on the last file, it reloads with the old version. What I need is to livereload after all jade files.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. What I had to do is create a new task called "Reload", put dependencies on it and run it after each of the other tasks. Here is the new Gulpfile":

'use strict';

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
var jeet = require('jeet');
var nib = require('nib');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var sources = {
  jade: "jade/**/*.jade",
  partials: "partials/**/*.jade",
  stylus: "styl/**/*.styl",
  scripts: "js/**/*.js"
};

// Define destinations object
var destinations = {
  html: "dist/",
  css: "dist/css",
  js: "dist/js"
};

// Compile and copy Jade
gulp.task("jade", function(event) {
  return gulp.src(sources.jade)
  .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.html))
});

// Compile and copy Stylus
gulp.task("stylus", function(event) {
  return gulp.src(sources.stylus).pipe(stylus({
    use: [nib(), jeet()],
    import: [
      'nib',
      'jeet'
    ],
    style: "compressed"
  })).pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.css));
});

// Minify and copy all JavaScript
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src(sources.scripts)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.js));
});

// Server
gulp.task('server', function () {
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/dist/'));
  app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0');
});

// Watch sources for change, executa tasks
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(sources.jade, ["jade", "refresh"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.partials, ["jade", "refresh"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.stylus, ["stylus", "refresh"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.scripts, ["scripts", "refresh"]);
});

// Refresh task. Depends on Jade task completion
gulp.task("refresh", ["jade"], function(){
  livereload.changed();
  console.log('LiveReload is triggered');
});

// Define default task
gulp.task("default", ["jade", "stylus", "scripts", "server", "watch"]);
```

Comment: Is it reloading your browser?

Comment: I don't remember, my friend. It was soo long ago :)